# Unable to set "mongod" PATH

Tags: macos, bash, mongodb, vim

I'm having issues trying to run `mongod` upon terminal start up.

**OS**

- OSX 10.11.4

**Steps so far:**

- Download OS X 10.7+ 64-bit
- Uncompress mongodb-osx-x86_64-3.2.5.tgz
- Rename mongodb-osx-x86_64-3.2.5 to mongodb
- Moved /mongodb to [Desktop/development]
- Add /data/db to Desktop/development/mongodb/bin
- Changed permissions to /data/db using `chmod 777 /data/db`

Within `Desktop/development/mongod/bin` typing `./mongod` everything is working as expected and I can access the the `mongo` shell. Now I would like to just be able to type `mongod` upon terminal startup and run both `mongo` and `mongod`

PATH for mongod

- Open bash file `vi ~/.bashrc`
- While in insert mode: `export PATH=Desktop/development/mongodb/bin:$PATH` I've also tried `export PATH=$Home/Desktop/development/mongodb/bin:$PATH`

What am I missing or doing wrong?

Thanks

**EDIT**

As per suggestions I've moved all the mongo files into a more appropriate locations.

- Mongo location: `$HOME/mongodb/bin`
- Mongo DB location: `$HOME/mongoData`
- `Data/db` location: `$HOME/mongoData/data/db`
- Bash command: `export PATH=$HOME/mongodb/bin:$PATH`

I'm thinking this is correct, but still unable to run `mongod` is there something missing in the bash command? Like `mongo = PATH=...`?

Comment: Note that on UNIX-like systems (which includes OS X) environment variables are case sensitive.  So `$Home` is probably an empty string, you need `$HOME`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Desktop` is actually `$HOME/Desktop` as it's in your home directory, so you need:

```
export PATH=$HOME/Desktop/development/mongodb/bin:$PATH
```

Desktop is not the place to put stuff as it's nothing much more than a convenience area that you can add to and remove from at a whim.  It's also too visible as you will see the folder icons.

You should have installed all that stuff into your home directory (or `/usr/local` if you want it available to all users).

Also "Add /data/db to Desktop/development/mongodb/bin" doesn't look right to me as data and executables are different.

If I was adding mongodb for development then I would have installed it via Macports with:

```
$ sudo port install mongodb
```

and would be up and working in less than 2 minutes.

Comment: Hey so moved quite a few things around as per your suggestions which make a lot more sense. I do want to say I tried Macports and everything worked perfectly. I will use it going forward but want to figure out my mistake setting up the paths. I've added the changes to an edit to my questions. Thanks again for the help so far

Comment: @Full-Hybrid The location `~/Users/steve/mongodb/bin` isn't right; it's simply `~/mongodb/bin` as `~` expands to `/Users/steve/`.

Comment: So I've updated the code again to. Just to be clear `~` is representative of `/Users/steve`? I've changed the bash profile and it still isn't working so I'm just extremely confused on how this is supposed to look and the exact proper locations. If I `cd ~`; `/mongoData and /mongodb` are both showing.

Comment: @Full-Hybrid Change all references of `~` to `$HOME` (all uppercase) as mentioned in my answer.

Comment: After adding the export line. `source ~/.bashrc` will be helpful in that we don't need to logoff and login again

Comment: So I've given up on the whole bash command to get `mongo` and `mongod` to run. No idea why it won't run but tired of trying and not making progress. I moved the mongodb directory into `/usr/local`. Than I opened up my paths with `sudo nano /etc/paths` and added `/usr/local/mongodb/bin`. Now everything is working. My only question now is how does running `mongod` even use anything in the paths file? Again thanks for the help, suggestions and patience. Brand new to system admin type stuff so apologies for any lack of comprehension.